# updating array of objects in state with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a shopping cart in react and want to be able to increase the quantity of an item with each click. All examples that I can find just push a new item to the array, rather than increasing the quantity of the existing item, resulting in something like:

```
[
{id: 1, item: pants, qty: 1},
{id: 1, item: pants, qty: 1},
{id: 2, item: shirt, qty: 1}
]
```

when my goal is to have:

```
[
{id: 1, item: pants, qty: 2},
{id: 2, item: shirt, qty: 1}
]
```

I've come up with the below which works, but it's super ugly. I’m looking for something more elegant.

```
    function App() {

      const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

      const updateState = (item) => (e) => {
        let newArray = [...items];

        if (items.some((el) => el.id === item.id)) {
          const place = items.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === item.id);
          newArray[place] = {
            id: item.id,
            item: item.name,
            qty: items[place].qty + 1,
          };
        } else {
          newArray.push({ id: item.id, item: item.name, qty: 1 });
        }

        console.log(newArray);
        setItems(newArray);
     };

     return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={updateState({ id: 1, name: 'pants' })}></button>
         <button onClick={updateState({ id: 2, name: 'shirt' })}></button>
       </div>
     );
   }
```

Here's a code sandbox of the working, ugly version. https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-resonance-f1ip6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What's your question? This doesn't look that bad although you can avoid the `.some` call and just use `findIndex`.

Comment: @Sam Your code is working as expected. what is the issue?

Comment: Just seems rather cumbersome for something I thought could be done more elegantly / easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. There is eventually libraries that could help you make the code prettier like [DotProp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dot-prop), but it will just handle what you are doing behind the scene.

Eventually, you could just avoid doing `.some(...)` by directly getting the indexOf and check if it's undefined in your if statement, but that does not change a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is fine, but to keep things clean I think you should create a new function that takes the array and the item and inserts the item if it doesn't already exist or updates the quantity of the item if the item exists in the array.

Here is another implementation.

```js
const arr = [
{id: 1, item: "pants", qty: 1},
{id: 2, item: "shirt", qty: 1}
]


const addItem = (arr, item) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(el => el.id === item.id);

  if (idx === -1) {
    return [...arr, item]
  }

  arr[idx] = {...arr[idx], qty: arr[idx].qty + 1}
  return [...arr];
}

let newArr = addItem(arr, {id: 1, item: "pants", qty: 1})
newArr = addItem(newArr, {id: 3, item: "jeans", qty: 1})
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is not ugly. Could you try?

```
import React from "react"
import "./styles.css"

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: 'pants'},
    {id: 2, name: 'shirt'}
  ])

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    setItems(items.map((item, curIndex) =>
           i === curIndex ? { ...item, qty: ++item.qty||1 } : item
    ))
  }

  return (
   <div>
     {items.map((item,index)=>(
       <button onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}>{item.qty || 0}</button>
     ))}
   </div>
 )
}
```